# nav with "last used"

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

Right now there are three options for the home tab settings. They are "new", "popular", and "need answers". I think they are fine choices, but I am often spending time repeatedly following a similar pattern of searching not covered by those three.

The pattern used tends to change frequently because I am looking in some sort of niche, and once that niche is thoroughly examined I move on to the next one.

I feel like when I am doing this my search settings are a complete unknown to the nav system which requires me to do things like duplicate tabs or constantly return to the one tab I have setup. It would save time if there was a way to have a home setting for these.

In the previous navigation version, the "Questions" button would return you to the most recent tab you were on. While it didn't do things like include selected tags, it still somewhat simply remembered where you were last.

I think a functionality which remembered where you were looking last as a home setting would save users a lot of time by increasing the ease for navigating to niches. It could simply *remember the last queryset* (or whichever metric is currently in use at this point) for questions sent, and just *reproduce that when the "Questions" button was clicked*.

[image]

**tl;dr; Having a "last used" setting for home will save time navigating and allow for more views on niche questions.**